# Proof writing involving propositional logic: (x ∨ y) ≡ ( x ∧ y ) → x ≡ y

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

**Prove by using propositional logic:**

(x ∨ y) ≡ ( x ∧ y ) → x ≡ y

I'm a bit lost here proving by propositional logic that the statement is valid. I don't know how to start this problem. Any help? I know the statement is true since x ≡ y, thus the premise (x ∨ y) ≡ ( x ∧ y ) does not matter, it will be still true according to the → operation. Any ideas? Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**Edit:**

Apart from true tables.

Comment: Fill  a truth table, it takes 10 seconds.

Comment: Not allowed to use truth tables, sadly. That's too easy.

Comment: Note that the other direction $\;\leftarrow\;$ is trivially true, and that $\;\equiv\;$ is associative, and therefore we have $$x \lor y \;\equiv\; x \land y \;\equiv\; x \;\equiv\; y$$ which Edsger W. Dijkstra et al. called the "golden rule" (source: [Dijkstra and Scholten, Predicate Calculus and Program Semantics](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-3228-5), page 37).  It is really quite versatile, given that $\;\equiv\;$ is not only associative but also symmetric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show that $x \equiv y$ from the premise $(x\vee y) \equiv (x \wedge y)$. I assume it's enough to derive $(x\to y) \wedge (y \to x)$.

1. $(x\vee y) \equiv (x \wedge y) \qquad \text{(premise)}$
2. Assume $x \qquad\qquad \text{(assumption)}$
3. $x \vee y \qquad\qquad\qquad \text{by $p \to (p \vee q)$}$
4. $x \wedge y\qquad\qquad\qquad \text{by 1.}$
5. $y \quad\qquad\qquad\qquad \text{by $(p\wedge q) \to q$}$
6. $x \to y \quad\qquad\qquad \text{by 2. and 5., discharging 2.}$
7. -- 11. similarly derive $y \to x$.

Comment: I like the step-by-step explanation, thanks but I'm a bit still confused. So we have to show that (x→y) and (y→x) by the premise, thus that proves that the statement is valid?

Comment: Yes. $(x \rightarrow y) \wedge (y \rightarrow x)$ is the definition of $x\equiv y$.

Comment: ohhh, I see now. thanks so much!

Comment: Yeah haha! thanks :)

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD or one possible definition. Another useful one is $(x\wedge y) \vee (\neg x \wedge \neg y)$.

Comment: @ Steve Sorry, I deleted the comment you laughed at! After I wrote it realized you were thanking @Yo so mine seemed dumb. But anyway, you're welcome, & I'm sure my fixing the last line helped :/